# Populate Dojo's datagrid with JsonRest and custom json arrays

Tags: json, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a grid that I am creating drawing off a JSON data source that is formatted like this:

```
[{"user":{"username":"foo","url":"bar"}},
   [{"product":{"name":"banana","price":"85"}},
    {"product":{"name":"peach","price":"66"}},
    {"product":{"name":"strawberry","price":"78"}}
   ]
]
```

But I cannot figure out how to tell datagrid to use the contents of the products to populate the datagrid. Here is my datagrid code:

```
        <script>
        require(["dojo/store/JsonRest"], function (JsonRest) {
            myStore = new JsonRest({ target: 'myurl', handleAs: 'json'
            });
        });

        require(["dojox/grid/DataGrid", "dojo/data/ObjectStore", "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function (DataGrid, ObjectStore) {
            grid = new DataGrid({
                store: dataStore = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: myStore }),
                structure: [
                    { name: "Procuct", field: "name", width: "200px" }
                ]
            }, "grid3");

            grid.startup();

        });
    </script>
    <div id="grid3"></div>
```

I do not get any error, but I cannot see that the grid gets populated.

It is a similar question to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226264/using-dojos-dgrid-jsonrest-and-subrows-arrays), but the data structure is a bit different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has something to do with your json structure.
The first part of your jsonArray is an object, the second an array:

[object,ArrayOfProducts]

How should DataGrid find the necessary data if you hide it in an array within an array & then inside the attribute product.
Try passing something simple via json like:

```
 [{"name":"banana","price":"85"},
  {"name":"peach","price":"66"},
  {"name":"strawberry","price":"78"}]
```

Comment: I am not able to change the json structure. Is it possible to change the structure prior somehow?

Comment: could you test my suggestion with a dummy url providing the data i posted to be sure, that this is the solution ?

Comment: I tried it with sinon to fake the json and your response suggestion. But I cant see the grid.

Comment: i pasted your code without sinon in a jsfiddle and everything is working, expect the data is not shown: http://jsfiddle.net/mWuQm/

Comment: which version of dojo are you using (should have asked that a long time ago) ?

Comment: It is 1.8.3. Yeah I know that I see something then, but I would like to fill it with my sinon fake data (but when I use var server = sinon.fakeServer.create(); nothing will show up anymore.

Comment: i used jsfiddle echo feature to give a json response and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/mWuQm/1/ you had two require statements i added them into one...

Comment: Not yet. Your answer is right, it is the wrong json structure. Now I figure out how to get nicer json :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried grid.renderArray(dataStore) to populate the grid with the conent ?

Answer (score 0):

An option is to append a new property to the json object prior to dataStore.query() call. This can be accomplished with [dojo/aspect](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/aspect.html). See [article](http://davidwalsh.name/dojo-aspect) for other examples.

```
aspect.before(dataStore, "query", function(items) {
    items.forEach(function(item) { 
        //Do something here. I'll combine two properties.
        item.newProperty = item.propertyValueA + "-" item.propertyValueB;
            return item;
        });
    return items;
});
```

When dataStore.query() is called, the function above is called above. This results in a new property be added to the json object. In the example above, the newProperty is a concatenation of propertyValueA and propertyValueB.

This may allow you to manipulate the json as needed.